# Нужно ли ставить запятую при обособлении приложения с помощью тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли здесь запятая?

«...» — один из крупных и известных российских поставщиков фланцев и деталей трубопроводов, подвел предварительные итоги 2014 года.

Также и в этом предложении - нужно ли ставить тире перед названием системы?

Сегодня на производстве ведутся работы по внедрению новой прогрессивной системы планирования и снабжения — «...», которая позволяет реализовать принцип «точно в срок».

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***В первом примере запятая не нужна***. Приложение здесь обособляется двумя тире:

Два тире используются "для выделения с двух сторон приложений, носящих пояснительный характер, например: Какая-то ненатуральная зелень – творение скучных беспрерывных дождей – покрывала жидкою сетью поля и нивы… (Гоголь); Легкие судороги – признак сильного чувства – пробежали по его широким губам… (Тургенев) (ср. § 89 (Обобщающие слова при однородных членах), п. 4); Смотритель ночлежки – отставной солдат скобелевских времён – шёл следом за хозяином (Федин).
     Второе тире опускается: если по условиям контекста после обособленного приложения ставится запятая, например: Используя специальное устройство для дыхания человека под водой – акваланг, можно погружаться на глубину в десятки метров; если приложение предшествует определяемому слову...". [Обособленные приложения](http://pravopisanie_i_stilistika.academic.ru/94/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

***Во втором предложении тире не нужно***, так как название системы даётся в кавычках и стоит после определяемого слова. Оно не согласуется с определяемым словом, тире неуместно. Предположим:  ***...новой системы... "Альфа".***

Answer (score 1):

Та, что уже стоит - нужна, но тире с ней не сочетается. Вместо него я поставил бы вторую запятую: основное утверждение состоит в том, что этот завод подвёл этоги, а характеристика завода здесь носит подчинённый, пояснительный характер. Возможен вариант с двумя тире (второе - вместо имеющейся запятой) - это подчеркнуло бы значимость характеристики завода на фоне сообщения о подведении итогов. Но по форме это более громоздко; для акцента на характеристике завода проще разбить фразу на две (в первой - оставить тире).

Answer (score 0):

В обоих предложениях с помощью тире обособляется приложение, носящее пояснительный характер. Правда, в первом предложении можно ограничиться и запятой.